# How to make sure if the video recorded is related to a specific App and not the device's Camera before I delete it Swift

Tags: swift

I'm using AVCaptureOutPut to record a video and upload to the server. I'm deleting the last video taken once I upload to the server. Everything works fine. 
Now I want to delete the video if the user recorded but doesn't want to upload and close the App. I've added same function to the AppDeletage's applicationWillTerminate function but it's picking up the personal video from iCloud if the user goes to the Record screen but like to close the App without recording.

How do I check if the particular video is recorded using the App and not thru the Camera?

Here is my code:

Recording and Saving Video in CaptureView Controller:

```
 @IBAction func handleMoviewRecord(_ sender: Any) {

        if videoRecordState == .stop {
//            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
//            let fileUrl = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("output.mov")
//            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileUrl)

            let tmpdir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
            outputPath = "\(tmpdir)output.mov"
            outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:outputPath as String)
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputPath) {
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: outputPath)
                } catch _ {
                }
            }
}
}

}

unc fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
            print("FINISHED \(Error.self)")

        // save video to camera roll

              if error == nil {

                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputPath){
                        if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(self.outputPath) {

                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputPath, nil, nil, nil)
                   // outputFileURL.path, nil, nil, nil)
                    UserDefaults.set(.videoPath, to: outputURL.path)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)
                    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
       }
    }
  }
}

App Delegate.Swift

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
            // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
            self.saveContext()
            clearTmpDirectory()

        }

       func clearTmpDirectory() {
             do {
                 let tmpDirURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
                let filePaths = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(tmpDirURL)")
                for filePath in filePaths {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + filePath)
                }
             } catch {
                //catch the error somehow
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not save it to the user's photo library. Just use the temporary file folder and stage your data there before uploading to your server.

```
let directory = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
/// create a new file there and write capture data to this directory
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response and I was caught up with some other work. So I've created the temp directory and saved the files there. But when I close the How should I update the AppDelegate func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) to handle that?

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect the change, please take a look. thanks

Comment: If the data is not extremely sensitive, you could just let iOS clean out that directory, which it does whenever the system runs low on space.

Comment: the data is not that sensitive, but why I'm seeing the video in the device Camera album? shouldn't it be in a temp folder which user couldn't see? Do you think the Saving to the album in my function is correct?